# LibGDX texture is used wrong for g3db model but was mapped correctly on uv map

Tags: kotlin, libgdx

I tried to render my g3db models in LibGDX but unfortunately the texture for the moder won't be applied just like I mapped it on the object. This is my code:

```
class WauWau : ApplicationAdapter() {
    companion object val tag = "WauWau"
    private lateinit var camera: PerspectiveCamera
    private lateinit var modelBatch: ModelBatch
    private lateinit var model: Model
    private lateinit var modelInstance: ModelInstance
    private lateinit var environment: Environment

    override fun create() {
        camera = PerspectiveCamera(75f, Gdx.graphics.width.toFloat(), Gdx.graphics.height.toFloat())
        camera.position.set(0f,100f,200f)
        camera.lookAt(0f, 100f, 0f)
        camera.near = 0.1f
        camera.far = 300.0f
        modelBatch = ModelBatch()
        val jsonReader = UBJsonReader()
        val modelLoader = G3dModelLoader(jsonReader)
        model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("card.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal))
        modelInstance = ModelInstance(model)
        environment = Environment()
        environment.set(ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f))
    }

    override fun render() {
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.width, Gdx.graphics.height)
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f)
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL30.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        camera.update()
        modelBatch.begin(camera)
        modelBatch.render(modelInstance)
        modelBatch.end()
    }

    override fun dispose() {
        modelBatch.dispose()
        model.dispose()
    }
}
```

Any suggestions what goes wrong with my model and maybe any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flipped the texture and now it works just fine!